Multiple userform conundrum
I have a macro where multiple userforms open and each have their own dedicated "Done" button which unloads the respective userforms.
Now, I have a separate Save function to copy the output sheet to a new workbook and save separately.
My intention is to call this save function when the Done button of the last userform is clicked. (User can randomly choose the order of closing the open userforms.)
I will have different cases where only one userform or 2 or even 3 different user forms open at the same time at the end of the process.
I am confused as to what logic should I use to do call save function only when the "done" button on the last user form is clicked.
How should I go about it?
THank you for your inputs.

If you got several Userforms opened at the same time I guess you are loading them with Modal=false. In that case, the command VBA.UserForms.Count will return how many userforms are currently loaded on screen. Maybe you can use it so if the count is 1 means that userform is the last one but not tested

Why is it necessary to keep all these user forms open? Then, do all the mentioned user forms have a 'Done' button? If so, does its code do the same thing, only saving the workbook? If it is really something making you to keep all of them open, you can disable that button to the all (already) open user forms, only the one from the last one being enabled. But not knowing/understanding why you really need so many user forms instead of doing everything using only one and not seeing any code, it is difficult to suggest a solution...

The entire macro itself is huge and not relevant, but depending on the inputs by the user 1, 2 or 3 different user forms having different codes (again not relevant here) open. Since each user form can open on its own depending on what the user has input initially, all of them need a done button to unload them when clicked. On top of that, I want to call the save function (which I have separately prepared) when the done button of the last user form is clicked.

@FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns thank you, I managed with userforms count. I added the command: If Not VBA.UserForms.count>1 Then (call save function) Works like a charm :)

Still I do not understand why you cannot do everything is necessary in a single user form, but supposing that you really have a reason let us clarify what this Done button existing on all user forms does. So, this mentioned Done button is used to unload the form and it (normally) does only this issue. And you need to save something (a workbook, many etc.) when the last shown such button is pressed. Is this a correct understanding of your existing many open forms situation? If so, do all these forms belong to the same workbook VBProject?

Yes, currently all done buttons on all user forms just unload the user forms. All the userforms belong to the same workbook VB project.

Now, do you want saving only if the last OPEN form Done button is clicked, or the Done button of the last remained open? I mean for the second case, only if a single such user form is loaded/open... Otherwise, pressing that button will only unload the form.

Example: there are 3 userforms open at the end of the whole process and the output is generated. Then User click done on first userform  (random) , that userform unloads. User clicks done on the second userform (again random), that userform unloads. User then clicks the last open user form, userform unloads and save function is called (triggering a message box “Do you want to save, yes,no” and following commands related to saving the sheet as a separate workbook)

Then, you need to place in the Terminate event a piece of code to determine the appropriate situation for saving. You should iterate between open forms, check if they belong to the same workbook (it maybe some other form from another workbook, add-in is open...) and save or not according to their count. In fact, I will place an answer. I have the solution in my mind and it should not take  more than 5 minutes...

Please, use the next scenario:

Move (if  not existing there) the sub saving the workbook in a standard module. For the code I will post it should be Sub SaveTheNecessaryWorkbook. With an argument related to the workbook to be saved, or not...

In UserForm_Terminate event of all involved such user forms, copy the next piece of code:


Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
 Dim frm As Object, CountFrm As Long
 For Each frm In VBA.UserForms
    If Not frm Is Me Then
        'check if other user form(s) from the same workbook are open:
        If IsFromSameWorkbook(frm.name, ThisWorkbook.name) Then CountFrm = CountFrm + 1
    End If
 Next
 If CountFrm = 0 Then SaveTheNecessaryWorkbook 'take care to have such a `Sub` in a standard module, or use here the existing one name, if it already exists.
End Sub

And the function able to determine if the open user form belongs to the same workbook, which to be copied somewhere in the user form code module. Maybe, immediately after the above Terminate event...
Function IsFromSameWorkbook(formName As String, WBNme As String) As Boolean
  Dim VbComp As Object
    For Each VbComp In Workbooks("" & WBNme & "").VBProject.VBComponents
        If VbComp.name = formName Then
         Let IsFromSameWorkbook = True: Exit Function
        End If
    Next VbComp
    IsFromSameWorkbook = False
End Function

A better idea would be to copy both of them, at once...
Now, the above solution will count how many forms belonging to the same workbook as the one keeping the code, except that one, are open and call the saving Sub only if the respective user form is the last remained one. CountFrm to be zero...
This solution should work even if you do not press Done. It also works if the top right X is pressed.
Please, send some feedback after testing it.

@Barbarian Didn't you find some time to test the above suggested solution? If tested, didn't it do what you need?
